# DispatcherServlet: redirect on page at localhost

Tags: java, spring, rest, redirect, localhost

I'am trying to test my @RestController on abbility of redirecting.

For testing aims it must redirect on localhost.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = RegistrationRestController.CONFIRM_REGISTRATION_URL, produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RegistrationRestController {

public static final String CONFIRM_REGISTRATION_URL = "/confirmRegistration";

@Autowired
UserService userService;

@GetMapping
public RedirectView confirmRegistration(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
    RedirectView redirectView;
    Token verificationToken = userService.getToken(token);
    if ((verificationToken == null) || (verificationToken.getExpiryDateTime().isAfter(LocalDateTime.now()))) {
        redirectView = new RedirectView("access_denied");
    } else redirectView = new RedirectView("access_approved");

    return redirectView;
    }

 }
```

Servlet mapping is:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I run application and enter:

```
 http://localhost:8080/test/confirmRegistration?token=a5582f4c-db3c-4d7c-9fab-7fd82ffb5d89
```

But I receive an 404-error.

When I use instead of "access_approved" absolute-path of real-sites (for example, "https://stackoverflow.com/") its working well.

So, the problem is focused on pages, which located at my-project-structure. Futher the screen of my wabapp is attached

[image: webapp-structure]

Answer (score 0):

Use `MockMvc` for testing controllers. Here is an example:
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-boot-mockmvc-example/